# Primefaces Fileupload Listener not invoked

Tags: primefaces

I am using the Prime faces file upload in advanced mode where it works fine in local system ,but in UAT the listener is not being called.why?
i tried many suggestions ,still the same issue exists.please help me.

UAT(Linux) i am using the tomee server
Local(Windows) tomcat server 
primefaces 5.3

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the listener is not called is ,there is an firewall restriction to the UAT server where the server is not accepting any file uploads from other domains,only people who are in their domain can access it ,and it is working for them.